# My transition don't work on google chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-transitions, compatibility

I'm looking for help because I made this transition below and it works on firefox but don't on google chrome :

```css
.item-2 .heart_animation {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 19px;
    bottom: 27px;
  }
  .item-2 .heart_animation .fa-heart::after {
    content: '\f004';
    position: relative;
    right: 1.7em;
    font-size: .4em;
    bottom: 25px;

    transition: transform 500ms ease-in;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: -6px;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .item-2 .heart_animation:active > .fa-heart {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#FF79DA), to(#9356DC));
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #FF79DA, #9356DC);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  .item-2 .heart_animation:active > .fa-heart::after {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.3);
            transform: scale(2.3);
  }
```

```html
<!-- FONT AWESOME -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css"  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
 <a href="./le_délice_des_sens.html" class="item-2">

                                        <img src="./assets/images/restaurants/Le_délice_des_sens.jpg" alt="Le_délice_des_sens">

                                        <div class="description_food">

                                            <h2>Le délice des sens</h2>
                                            <p>Folie-Méricourt</p>

                                        </div>

                                        <div class="heart_animation">
                                            <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    
                            </a>
```

So the transition on :active make grow up another heart and filled it with background : linear-gradient  to the first one.

On Firefox,the heart is filled with the background :linear-gradient :
[image: Filled Heart]

On Google Chrome, the heart have the background only on the edges of the heart on :active but it seems that the transition don't work but I'm not sure ! :

[image: Not filled]

I check on MDN WEB DOCS if there is any compatibility issue but all of properties  works fine on both browser.

Could you help me to understand why I have this ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you check your snippet as when I run it no filling of the heart happens (well, it might happen for and instant and then things go blank).

Comment: When you stand on the heart (on click) the background linear-gradient work on the edges but the transition don't work at all  and If I remove the property visibility:hidden; you can see that there is another heart that should grow to fill the first one but it's not on chrome